# Set button to look like default android button

Tags: android, button, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

please how to set an android widget button to look like default ICS button?

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/toggleUpdaterService"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contextLabel"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="@string/StartUpdaterService" />
```

This code I use for including the widget in my layout, but the resulting button look like only simple rectangle button with gray background..I would like to make it look like a native ICS button with dark background..

Please help how to achieve that..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use following attribute in background of button:

android.R.drawable.btn_default

Comment: I added this to my xml         `android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"`, but unfortunately id didnt work for me..